# Stop window refreshing in Live Preview?

Tags: plugin-development, live-preview

I am working on LivePreview and the window it's get loaded at every change. It is possible to do that only when I will click the Save button?

Answer (score 2):

No, that’s the whole point of Live Preview, to update and preview the changes “live”.

If that’s not what you want you can save the entry via “Save an continue editing” (keyboard shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then view the changes by clicking the “Entry link” button.

[image: Share entry]

Comment: Thanks. I want to update an preview the changes "live" , but in my case I have the content rendered in a iframe and every time I change a letter it's get reloaded the entire content.

Comment: Yeah, the site preview is loaded into an iframe and updated on changes to any of the input fields. That’s how it works.

Comment: @user6644 You can use `craft.request.isLivePreview()` (returns a boolean) inside your template to hide/disable the iframe when in livepreview.